# AWS How to get List of triggers with each dynamodb table using java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

There is a dynamodb table which has triggers in the triggers tab. How to get the list of those triggers using AWS Java SDK for a given table.
I have gone through the JAVA SDK but so far have not been able to find any API to get the list.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-event-source-mappings.html

Java:

```
AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().build();
ListEventSourceMappingsRequest request = new ListEventSourceMappingsRequest().withEventSourceArn("your table stream arn");
ListEventSourceMappingsResult result = client.listEventSourceMappings(request);
List<EventSourceMappingConfiguration> eventSourceMappings = result.getEventSourceMappings();
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe these operations are part of DynamoDB Streams - see [listStreams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBStreams.html#listStreams-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ListStreamsRequest-)

Comment: This returns the "Latest stream ARN" but not the list of Lambdas to which the events are streamed. The right way is as described by "xrcsblue".